# Perl: constants and compile-time vs runtime hash lookups?

Tags: perl, hash, constants

In Perl 5.26, constant-based hash lookups appear to be resolved at compile-time, not runtime. How can I enforce it to be resolved at runtime?

Consider the following reduced testcase, boiled down from a hash-based state-machine I was trying to write, where the key is the state identifier and the value is the state function.

```
use constant {
    STATE_1 => 1,
    STATE_2 => 2,
};

my %fsm;

%fsm = (
    STATE_1, sub {
        $fsm{STATE_2}->(@_);
        return STATE_2;
    },
    STATE_2, sub {
        return STATE_1;
    }
);

my $state = STATE_1;

$state = $fsm{$state}->();
```

Note that in `STATE_1`, I'm trying to call the `STATE_2` function.

However, at runtime I get this:

```
Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference at ./self-reference-hash.pl line 15.
```

Which indicates that the `$fsm{STATE_2}->(@_);` line in `STATE_1` is undefined. And indeed, at the time where this line first appears, the `STATE_2` function isn't defined *yet*, but I was counting on hash lookups being resolved at runtime.

If I instead replace `$fsm{STATE_2}->(@_);` with `my $tmp = STATE_2; $fsm{$tmp}->(@_);` then it works as expected, which seems hacky.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: `use Const::Fast; const my $STATE_1 => 1;` seems to fit?  You can also declare array, hash (and their refs) with it.

Comment: Maybe, though I'd like to avoid adding external dependencies that complicate distribution.

Comment: I think your states should be strings anyway. It's a little weird using integers as hash keys. Just remove the `constant` definitions and quote the state names.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely my C background wanting me to use well-defined constants as identifiers...

Comment: @John: Strings are also well-defined constants. The difference is that C has no hash structure!

Answer (score 13):

The source of this problem is actually explained in [Perl's doc about `constant`](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html#CAVEATS), and it's not about runtime vs compile-time, but about Perl magically quoting barewords in some contexts:

> You can get into trouble if you use constants in a context which
>   automatically quotes barewords (as is true for any subroutine call).
>   For example, **you can't say `$hash{CONSTANT}` because `CONSTANT` will be
>   interpreted as a string.** Use `$hash{CONSTANT()}` or `$hash{+CONSTANT}` to
>   prevent the bareword quoting mechanism from kicking in. Similarly,
>   since the => operator quotes a bareword immediately to its left, you
>   have to say `CONSTANT() => 'value'` (or simply use a comma in place of
>   the big arrow) instead of `CONSTANT => 'value'` .

The listed workarounds resolve the issue.